# Clever way to validate get parameter in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

When you're writing a form you can configure the zend_form_element objects according to your needs. (Adding validators and filters)

Is there a clever way to achieve the same for the validation of "pure" GET parameters?

My task is to make sure that the application is secure and I am thinking about using the form validators and their chaining capability to check GET parameters.

I know how to do this in pure php, but I am wondering if there is a nice way to do this the "Zend way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Zend_Filter_Input`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) might be what you are looking for. It basically does the same as `Zend_Form` without the element and rendering stuff.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I missed that one :-)